# Уникализация вкладок в jQuery [$.tabs()]

Tags: jquery

Есть некая админка, где разделы открываются во вкладках от jQuery [$.tabs()]. Все прекрасно работает, за исключением того, что при открывании одного и того же раздела дважды, создаются две вкладки.

Вопрос такой: Как сделать, так, чтобы вкладки были уникальные. То есть, если раздел был открыт во вкладке, то при повторном открытии не создавалась новая вкладка, а активировалась та, которая была открыта с этим разделом? И так для каждой вкладки.

```
var ui_panel_index=false;
    var taby=new Array();
    var $tabs=$("#mtab").tabs({
     add: function(event, ui){

        $tabs.tabs("select","#"+ui.panel.id );
        ui_panel_index=ui.index;
    },
    tabTemplate: '<li><table style="font-size:12px;margin: 0; padding: 0"><tr><td><a href="#{href}"><span>#{label}</span></a></td><td><a                                  href="#{href}" class="close_tab"><img src="http://www.bambinipronto.com.au/images/icon_close_window.jpg" width="15px" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></li>'
    });    
    $(".close_tab").live("click", function(){
    var this_u=$(this).attr("href");
    var now_i=$.inArray(this_u,taby);
    //alert(now_i);
    if(now_i > 0){
        $tabs.tabs("remove", now_i);
        delete taby[now_i];
    }
    return false;
    });

    $("#menu label").bind("click",function() {

        var this_url=$("a", this).attr('href');
        var this_text=$("a", this).text();
        var now_index=$.inArray(this_url, taby);
            if(now_index > 0){
                 $tabs.tabs("select",now_index);
            }else{
                 $tabs.tabs("add", this_url, this_text);
                 taby[ui_panel_index]=this_url;
            }
         return false;
     });
```

Вот то что сам накидал. Все работает, только если закрывать вкладки, в случайном порядке, то последняя не закрывается, если закрыть с конца, то все закрываются...в чем ошибка?

**Исправление:** - рабочая версия.

```
var taby = new Array();
var $tabs=$("#mtab").tabs({
    add: function(event, ui){
            $tabs.tabs("select","#"+ui.panel.id );
        },
        remove:function(event, ui){
            var url=$.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
            delete taby[url];
        },
        load: function(event, ui){      
            var url=$.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
            var panel_id=ui.panel.id;
            taby[url]=panel_id;
        },
        spinner: 'Загрузка...',
        tabTemplate: '<li><table style="font-size:12px;margin: 0; padding: 0"><tr><td><a href="#{href}"><span>#{label}</span></a></td><td><a href="#{href}" class="close_tab"><img src="http://www.bambinipronto.com.au/images/icon_close_window.jpg" width="15px" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></li>'
});

$("#menu label").bind("click",function() {
    var this_url=$("a", this).attr('href');
    if(taby[this_url]==undefined){
        $tabs.tabs("add", this_url, $("a",this).text());
    }else{
        $tabs.tabs("select","#"+taby[this_url]);
    }
});

$(".close_tab").live("click", function(){
    var this_url = $(this).attr("href");
    $tabs.tabs("remove", taby[this_url]);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Детально код не смотрел, но эти строки бросились в глаза:

```
var now_i = $.inArray(this_u, taby);
if(now_i > 0){
    // ...
}
```

Функция inArray возвращает индекс элемента в массиве, либо -1, если элемент не найден. Соответственно проверка `now_i > 0` некорректна, и упускает случай, если элемент имеет индекс 0 в массиве. Попробуйте поменять Ваш код на:

```
var now_i = $.inArray(this_u, taby);
if(now_i >= 0){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, не изменилось ничего.